# Remove event listener when $scope is destroy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m actually facing a problem.

I have a directive that listens on an event like :

```
$scope.$on('event',myFunc);
```

The problem is that when the controller is destroyed, the $scope keeps the event listener alive..

What code should I put in

```
$scope.$on('$destroy',myDestroyFunc);
```

to prevent this effect ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Answer (score 1):

you should listen for scope destroy event and deregister from event on destroy.
$on returns a deregister function for events.

```
var deregister = $scope.$on('event',myFunc);
$scope.$on('$destroy', deregister);
```

Comment: can you post complete source of your directive?

Answer (score 0):

Just save reference to your event and use it in `$destroy`

```
var myFuncEvent = $scope.$on('event', myFunc);
$scope.$on('$destroy', myFuncEvent);
```